# Python: How do I change this merge loop by vectorization (aka Numpy) or any faster way to process?

Tags: python, vector

anyone can help on this code to make run faster by using vector or any other ways to improve on this ? it take about 1h to get to 120 loops... and I need to get to 365 which may not be attainable....

df and df2 are similar dataset and the key to join are the DateX and Tenor. The date will change according to a new days adding to it by the tenor.

Thanks

```
for i in range (1,120):
   print(i)
   df['DateX'+str(i)] = df['DateX'+str(i-1)] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Tenor'],unit='d')

   df2 = df2.rename(columns={'DateX' + str(i-1): 'DateX' + str(i)})
   df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Rate'  + str(i-1): 'Rate' + str(i)})
   
   df = pd.merge(df,df2[['DateX'+str(i), 'Rate'  + str(i-1), 'Tenor']], how='left', on= 
        ['Tenor','DateX'+str(i)])
```